# Stata does not read my Excel sheet correctly

Tags: excel, stata

I have to work with Stata. I got all my necessary data in Excel, but when I import them into Stata some data will be shown (as with the `sum` command) and some will be `no observations` or `not found`. I get these outputs

```
. summarize

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
total_assets |      2576    66822.33    236144.5      630.8    2573126
   employees |      2570    67.61437    160.5821       .175       2200
changeofwo~e |         0
employeedo~g |         0
   netincome |      2575    1683.551    4054.371     -99289      26895
     revenue |      2575    22475.59    40565.01  -4234.472     483521
         ROA |      2576    .0607231    .0734222  -.8526002   .5033718
 changeinROA |         0
           L |         0
           M |         0

. describe

Contains data
  obs:         2,577                          
 vars:            13                          
 size:       224,199                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label

firm_ID         int    %10.0g                 firm_ID
gvkey           long   %10.0g                 gvkey
fiscal_year     int    %10.0g                 fiscal_year
total_assets    double %10.0g                 total_assets
employees       double %10.0g                 employees
changeofworkf~e str18  %18s                   change of workforce
employeedowns~g str1   %9s                    employee downsizing
netincome       double %10.0g                 netincome
revenue         double %10.0g                 revenue
ROA             double %6.4f                  ROA
changeinROA     str18  %18s                   change in ROA
L               byte   %10.0g                 
M               byte   %10.0g                 
-
Sorted by:  
     Note:  dataset has changed since last saved



. sum ROA

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
         ROA |      2576    .0607231    .0734222  -.8526002   .5033718

. sum changeofworkforce

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
changeofwo~e |         0
```

same happens for `changeinROA`, or `employeedownsizing`.

FURTHER EDIT:

```
. tab downsizing

 downsizing |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |      2,168       84.19       84.19
          1 |        407       15.81      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      2,575      100.00
```

Comment: You need to ask a question that can be answered. Most of this post does not bear on your problem at all: we're sympathetic but who you are and other personal stuff doesn't illuminate the Stata problem one tiny bit. I've edited out uninformative detail. What exactly are you trying to import: .xls, .xlsx, something else? How are you trying to import it? `import delimited`, `import excel`, something else?

Comment: Look carefully at what Stata is reading as numeric and what as string variables. If necessary, show us the results of `describe` and `summarize`.

Comment: Variable        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
 fiscal_year       2576    2007.859    3.775437       2001       2014
total_assets       2576    66822.33    236144.5      630.8    2573126
   employees       2570    67.61437    160.5821       .175       2200
changeofwo~e        0
employeedo~g        0
         ROA        2576    .0607231    .0734222  -.8526002   .5033718

 changeinROA |         0
           L |         0
           M |         0

Comment: Relevant FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/numeric-variables-input-as-string/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your variables, namely

```
changeofwo~e 
employeedo~g 
 changeinROA
```

are being read as `string` variables. You can try `destring` (see its help for options) if you think they should really be numeric. In any case, a command like this

```
tab changeinROA if missing(real(changeinROA))
```

will show which values prevent Stata reading this as numeric (if you think it should be).

`employeedownsizing` may be a variable coded `Y`/`N` or some such for yes or no.

`L` and `M` are just full of missing values and contain no data.

Comment: employeedownsizing is indeed coded as 0 for <5% and 1 for > 5% , is that a problem?

Comment: So why is it being read as `string`?  You should `destring` it.

Comment: I don't know. I had it coded as destring before. Don't know what happened. First time using stata. when I want to do a logistic regression however it seems as if the 0 and 1 is incorrect as I'm being told that 
outcome does not vary; remember:
                                  0 = negative outcome,
        all other nonmissing values = positive outcome
0 should stand for "not downsizing", 1 for "downsizing" - or did I get that one wrong too?

Comment: What did you try? What was the exact `logit` or `logistic` command? What happens with `tab employeedownsizing`?

Comment: . tab downsizing

 downsizing |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |      2,168       84.19       84.19
          1 |        407       15.81      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      2,575      100.00
and this is what I did . logit changeinROA downsizing

outcome does not vary; remember:
                                  0 = negative outcome,
        all other nonmissing values = positive outcome
thanks so much for your help Nick!

Comment: As before, edit your question: see question for what you should have done. On the evidence you've given, `changeinROA` is a string variable and a logit regression would be futile while it's a string variable. But the logit should not produce that error message if it was a string variable. Tentative conclusion: You're using different versions of your data at different times and not telling us about that. That would be a waste of everyone's time here.